# Popstate with Hashtags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a site that uses AJAX to dynamically load content into a div.

The links to do so are anchors with href="#" and an onclick event to trigger the AJAX.

This leaves me without a history when I click back, so if I load one page, then another and click back, it does nothing.

A basic version of the code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
<!-- Load XML Script here. -->
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="myDiv">

<!-- Target div. -->

</div>

<a href="#1" onclick="loadXMLDoc('1.txt')">Click Me.</a>

<a href="#2" onclick="loadXMLDoc('2.txt')">Click Me.</a>

<a href="#3" onclick="loadXMLDoc('3.txt')">Click Me.</a>

</body>
```

What I would like to know is, can I give each link a different "#" and then use a popstate handler to call the appropriate event, so if I click link 1, 2 and then 3 and then start hitting the back button, it'll go back to 2 and then 1 etc..

I was going to use history.js and start using pushstate in the loadXML script but I think the whole manipulating history thing is a bit dirty and unreliable.

Am I thinking on the right lines or is there a better way?

Currently all my links just use "#" so that it pops back to the top of the page when loading more content but I'd like to be able to go back if possible.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser saves hashtags to history properly. Just add hashtag #1 to this question page, hit enter, change it to #2, hit enter, change it to #3, hit enter. Now click back button, and you'll see hash changes from #3 to #2. I recommend to change only hash itself on link click and react on page hash change and page load events.

```
function react() {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace("#", "");
    loadXMLDoc(hash + ".txt");
};

document.body.onload = function() {
    react();
    window.onhashchange = react;    
};

<a href="#1">Click me</a>
<a href="#2">Click me</a>
<a href="#3">Click me</a>
```

Please note that `onhashchange` event does not supported by old IE. The only way to deal with it if you want is to define timer with setInterval and check hashes equality.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks! Found some intresting for myself.
But, getting data on each back isn't perfect practice. Storing it somewhere (SessionStorage or LocalStorage) is better from perfomance point of view.

Comment: Right, in case data is not changes frequently, cache it's a good idea.

Comment: The browser already _has_ a cache implemented, and if handled right it works for documents loaded via AJAX in the same way as for “normally” loaded documents.

Comment: Thanks Tommi :-) exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I already knew that it saves the hashes but I was looking for the correct handler. Didn't know there was an onhashchange event. Been years since I've done any coding. I used to use iframes so history handling was never a problem, but I never really liked iframes so I swapped to dynamically loading to a div this time. It's given me a nice clean layout but a whole list of other things to think about! Thought I'd ask the chaps on here as you all seem to be friendly and knowledgeable. Thanks again^_

Answer (score 0):

Try to use combination of LocalStorage and HistoryAPI.
When you load XMLDoc store it in LocatStorage, when back is pressed - load data from storage, not from web.
A bit code above.

```
 /* Handling history.back added */
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
      yourHandleBackFunction(event.state);
    };

function yourHandleBackFunction(renderTs) {
      /*Check TS and load from localStorage if needed*/
  };
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry :-) optimisation is always something I like to keep in mind.